# read little endian 16 bit unsigned integer

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, terminal, terminfo

I'm looking into parsing [terminfo](http://man.cx/terminfo(4)) database files, which are a type of binary files. You can read about its [storage format](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html#h3-STORAGE-FORMAT) by your own and confirm the problem I'm facing.

The manual says -

> The header section begins the file.  This section contains
>     six  short  integers in the format described below.  These
>     integers are
>
> (1) the magic number (octal 0432);
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> **Short integers are stored in two 8-bit bytes.   The  first
>      byte  contains  the least significant 8 bits of the value,
>      and the second byte contains the most significant 8  bits.
>      (Thus,  the  value  represented is 256*second+first.)  The
>      value -1 is represented by the two bytes 0377, 0377; other
>      negative  values  are  illegal**. This value generally means
>      that the corresponding capability  is  missing  from  this
>      terminal. **Machines where this does not correspond to the
>      hardware must read the integers as two bytes  and  compute
>      the little-endian value**.

---

- The first problem while parsing this type of input is that it fixes the size to 8 bits, so the plain old char cannot be used since it doesn't guarantees the size to be exactly 8 bits. So I was lookin '[**Fixed width integer types**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)' but again was faced with dillema of choosing b/w `int8_t` or `uint8_t` which clearly states - "provided only if the implementation directly supports the type". So what should I choose so that the type is portable enough.
- The second problem is there is no `buffer.readInt16LE()` method in c++ standard library which might read 16 bytes of data in Little Endian format. So how should I proceed forward to implement this function again in a portable & safe way.

I've already tried reading it with `char` data type but it definitely produces garbage on my machine. Proper input can be read by `infocmp` command eg - `$ infocmp xterm`.

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream db(
      "/usr/share/terminfo/g/gnome", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;

    if (db) {
        auto size = db.tellg();
        buffer.resize(size);
        db.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        db.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer.front()), size);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

---

```
$1 = std::vector of length 3069, capacity 3069 = {26 '\032', 1 '\001', 21 '\025',
  0 '\000', 38 '&', 0 '\000', 16 '\020', 0 '\000', 157 '\235', 1 '\001',
  193 '\301', 4 '\004', 103 'g', 110 'n', 111 'o', 109 'm', 101 'e', 124 '|',
  71 'G', 78 'N', 79 'O', 77 'M', 69 'E', 32 ' ', 84 'T', 101 'e', 114 'r',
  109 'm', 105 'i', 110 'n', 97 'a', 108 'l', 0 '\000', 0 '\000', 1 '\001',
  0 '\000', 0 '\000', 1 '\001', 0 '\000', 0 '\000', 0 '\000', 0 '\000',
  0 '\000', 0 '\000', 0 '\000', 0 '\000', 1 '\001', 1 '\001', 0 '\000',
....
....
```

Comment: post some code my friend. try reading some bytes into a buffer and take a look at it with your debugger.

Comment: `char` is guaranteed to be the smallest addressable unit on any system (that's why `sizeof(char)` is specified to always be `1`). So for a system with 8-bit bytes `char` is guaranteed to be 8 bits. And since it's practically *all* systems made in the last 30 years or so there's really no need to worry. If you need to port your program to some old 1970's (or older) system *then* you might need to worry about it, but not otherwise.

Comment: You should use `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`.  The `char` type can be `unsigned`, `signed` or `char` *depending on the compiler setting*.

Comment: I'd always recommend to use the fixed with integer types. They should be available on any compiler that has even rudimentary support for C++11.

Comment: 1) add an assert; `CHAR_BIT==8`. 2) Don't fall into the trap of the [byte order fallacy](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).

Comment: As one answer says, if your code doesn't work using `char` then your code is broken.

Comment: @johnelemans added code and sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first problem while parsing this type of input is that it fixes the size to 8 bits, so the plain old char cannot be used since it doesn't guarantees the size to be exactly 8 bits.

Any integer that is at least 8 bits is OK. While `char` isn't guaranteed to be exactly 8 bits, it is required to be at least 8 bits, so as far as size is concerned, there is no problem other than you may in some cases need to mask the high bits if they exist. However, `char` might not be unsigned, and you don't want the octets to be interpreted as signed values, so use `unsigned char` instead.

> The second problem is there is no buffer.readInt16LE() method in c++ standard library which might read 16 bytes of data in Little Endian format. So how should I proceed forward to implement this function again in a portable & safe way.

Read one octet at a time into an `unsigned char`. Assign the first octet to the variable (that is large enough to represent at least 16 bits). Shift the bits of the second octet left by 8 and assign to the variable using the compound bitwise or.

Or better yet, don't re-implement it, but use an third party existing library.

> I've already tried reading it with char data type but it definitely produces garbage on my machine.

Then your attempt was buggy. There is no problem inherent with `char` that would cause garbage output. I recommend using a debugger to solve this problem.

Comment: I've added the code and sample output, would you mind telling me what am I doing wrong with it.

Comment: hmm so I tried defining two `unit8_t` vars `x` & `y`, and read data using - `db.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));` and then did what you suggested in another `unit16_t` - `result = x | (y << 8);` and the result was `282` which is indeed `0432` in octal. Not so sure why debugger output was like that. So does this method works on both little and big endian machine?

Comment: Yes, this converts little endian to native endian, regardless of what the native endianness is.

Comment: "Or better yet, don't re-implement it, but use an existing library."     What library? Is there any standard one?

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc I meant to refer to third party libraries specifically. There are no functions for this in the c++ standard library, but there is in the POSIX standard C library. Boost has very nice set of tools for this as well.